# jQuery flotcharts - add single value to yaxis label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, flot

How to add single value to yaxis label? Just like this 80 value:
[image]

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried

Comment: I didnt try any code. I just want to know if it is possible to do pure in jQuery FlotCharts. Image is edited in graphic prog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the line use [markings](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid), for example add this to your chart options:

```
grid: {
    markings: [ { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 2000 }, yaxis: { from: 80, to: 80 }, color: "black" }, ... ]
    ...
}
```

Change the `from` and `to` values according to your needs and `min/max` values.

2) For the value on the axis you have to add it manually like this (see the [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/annotating/index.html)):

```
var o = plot.pointOffset({ x: plot.getAxes().xaxis.min, y: 80.0});
$(plot.getPlaceholder()).append("<div style='position:absolute;right:" + (o.left - 4) + "px;top:" + o.top + "px;color:red;font-size:smaller;text-align:right'>80</div>");
```

Comment: Thanks for 'markings', also need it. I see it is not possible to add single value on axis by pure FlotChart. Its good what u answer but when i panning my flot top/bottom i would need to manipulate this div to fix his position.